# Implementing login functionality in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm going to implement login functionality using zend framework 2.

My code as follows.

```
$dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(array(
                    'driver' => 'Mysqli',
                    'database' => 'db',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'password'
            ));

$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);

            $authAdapter
            ->setTableName('admin_users')
            ->setIdentityColumn('user_name')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ;
$authAdapter
            ->setIdentity($username)
            ->setCredential($password)
            ;
$result = $authAdapter->authenticate();
```

It gives error message as follows.

```
The supplied parameters to DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
```

I checked database configurations and column names. But they are correct. Can anyone give me a clue to check this out please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to re-invent the wheel and struggle with this yourself. ZF2 has been created with modularity in mind so that plug in modules for this kind of thing can be written.

There are a few such modules available already at the [ZF-Commons](https://github.com/ZF-Commons) site. The one you are looking for is [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser). Just follow the instructions to install and use it. There is even an excellent tutorial written by the author of the module that will take you through the whole process step by step. http://blog.evan.pro/getting-started-with-the-zf2-skeleton-and-zfcuser

There is also an excellent [how-to](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki) page to tell you how to modify it for your own use.

Comment: I read few. but not all. Ok. Thanks vascowhite. I will go through them and let u know.

Comment: Thanks vascowhite. I was struggle to write a login because I'm restructuring old system with zf2. There are few user tables. I think i have to merge them using foreign keys to one table. Will try.

Comment: But as you can see in the documentation main features esp. for business environments are missing: _Support for additional authentication mechanisms via plugins (Google, Facebook, LDAP, etc) [INCOMPLETE]_